# E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/brightbox/ruby-ng-experimental/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, server, repository, ruby

This question is similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416361/the-repository-https-ppa-launchpadcontent-net-ubuntu-vn-ppa-ubuntu-jammy-rele) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417682/the-repository-https-cli-github-com-packages-jammy-release-does-not-have-a-r) but those aren't really helpful.
I am trying to install the Ruby libraries and packages that [Canvas](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Production-Start) needs. need to add a PPA in order to get the required Ruby version, by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get update
```

Upon adding repository, I am getting this error:

```
PPA publishes dbgsym, you may need to include 'main/debug' component
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
Ubuntu packages for Ruby 2.7, 2.6, 2.5, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.1, 2.0 1.9.3 and 1.8.

See https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/ for more details.

Discussion list here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/brightbox-ruby-ubuntu-packaging

https://www.brightbox.com
More info: https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brightbox-ubuntu-ruby-ng-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brightbox-ubuntu-ruby-ng-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brightbox-ubuntu-ruby-ng-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brightbox-ubuntu-ruby-ng-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brightbox-ubuntu-ruby-ng.gpg with fingerprint 80F70E11F0F0D5F10CB20E62F5DA5F09C3173AA6
Hit:1 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease
Hit:6 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Ign:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Err:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Hit:11 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/jammy-pgdg/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

So if I try to install ruby 2.7 without running above commands, it will give an error which is obvious [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDSJS.png)
I couldn't find any workaround as official documentation says the same.

I am using:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources, so all security checks (are they maintained, good for your computer, etc) are on you.  A quick look using the detail in your question shows support for many releases up to *focal* or 20.04, but **not** 22.04 or *jammy*.  Did you check?   eg. https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng

Comment: @guiverc No, It didn't resolve the issue. I have tried the first answer.

Comment: That PPA doesn't support *jammy* or your 22.04 release; it was a mistake to add it to your system because of that [*lack of*] support; you need to remove it (ie. *remove the PPAs from your system*)